# Resolve the module loaded by plugin in Webpack config

Tags: node.js, webpack

The following [example](https://github.com/webpack/imports-loader#webpackconfigjs) will work only if `some-module` module is Node module, and won't work for modules loaded by Webpack plugin.

How can Webpack's own logic ([enhanced-resolve](https://github.com/webpack/enhanced-resolve)) be used to resolve module paths in config?

In my case it was [bower-webpack-plugin](https://github.com/lpiepiora/bower-webpack-plugin), but I guess this should work in the same way with any `ResolverPlugin`

```
var BowerWebpackPlugin = require("bower-webpack-plugin");
module.exports = {
    ...
    module: {
        plugins: [new BowerWebpackPlugin()],
        loaders: [
            {
                // this won't work
                test: require.resolve("some-bower-module")
                loader: "imports?this=>window"
            }
        ]
};
```

Comment: I think loader tests need to be a RegExp object: http://webpack.github.io/docs/using-loaders.html#configuration

Comment: @sirlancelot I had to use regexps as workarounds they are fragile. I would prefer to match the modules by their names if possible.

Answer (score 1):

`require.resolve` inside `webpack.config.js` is resolved by Node and not Webpack's resolver. You can use `require("path").resolve("path/to/bower/module")` to get the full path to your Bower module.

Comment: That's right. The question is how to use Webpack resolver instead. Sure thing, it's not the easiest question, considering how Webpack is documented. I don't feel confortable to hard-code "path/to/bower/module", it is exactly what I'm trying to not do by using plugins.

Comment: Webpack can't use its own resolver logic while your configuring its resolver logic.

Comment: Can't I require `enhanced-resolve` and resolve module path with its plugins? I suspect that I can.